# Change admin server url with @EnableAdminServer

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using @EnableAdminServer in SpringBoot application. Once it's enabled, my mapping for `/` is replaced by the admin server.

Then I tried to change the admin server to another port or another URL base:

```
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8081
```

But it's not applied somehow. What should I do?

**EDIT**

pom.xml

```
   <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    ....

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    ....
```

Comment: Have you done all the other steps to setup the admin server already? https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/1.4.3/#set-up-admin-server

Answer (score 0):

That is not a valid configuration property anymore, it was previously a property you set in the client to tell it where to find the admin server and not a configuration property for the server itself. Check the [current documentation](https://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/current/#_configuration_options) for the right property names.

You set the port of Spring Boot including the admin server with:

```
server:
    port: 8080
```

Url base is determined by the DNS name of the host you deploy the application on so that will never be a configuration. There is however the property `spring.boot.admin.ui.public-url` but that is only used to fix links that might break behind a reverse proxy.

Comment: I think it should be `spring.boot.admin.context-path`, but that doesn't work either

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to mount the GUI on  `/someotherurl`. In your question you only mentioned port and url base with which I thought you meant domain.

Comment: I want the admin url to be something else than `/`

Comment: Well you can change the `server.servlet.context-path=/someotherurl`, but it will affect the whole application, not just the admin parts.

Comment: So there's no way to change the admin url only

Comment: Hmm I thought that `spring.boot.admin.context-path` was supposed to move not just the static resources and API but the GUI as well, but since you already tried that I'm out of ideas. Are you sure you are running the latest version?